# Web-crawler loop

Tags: python, loops, web-crawler

I wrote the following loop in my web crawler.

It runs out after some seconds. I can't figure out why.

```
def crawlweb(seed):
    crawled = []
    tocrawl = [seed]
    page = tocrawl[0]
    while tocrawl:
        if page not in crawled:
            tocrawl = tocrawl[1:] + (get_links(get_page(page)))
            crawled.append(page)
    return crawled, tocrawl
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def crawl_web(seed)
tocrawl = [seed]
crawled = []
while tocrawl:
    page = tocrawl.pop()
    if page not in crawled:
        union(tocrawl, get_all_links(get_page(page)))
        crawled.append(page)
return crawled
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion